# What plugins or tools do you use for user management in Grails?

Tags: authentication, grails, authorization, shiro, email-validation

What plugins or tools do you use for user management in Grails? 
I would like to use shiro for the security purpose and found [nimble](http://snimavat.github.io/nimble/). But this plugin is no more maintained and have dependency problems in grails 2.4.X.

I am interested in 
1.email verification
2.password recovery

What should be your suggestions regarding this?

Or is the only choice is to develop it on top of shiro grails integration by using email plugin?

Thank you.

Comment: Spring security core: http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core and Spring security UI: http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui are valid options.

Comment: Spring security core: grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core is nice alternative for shiro. But I am curious if there is a lightweight alternative for the Spring security UI: grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui.